# What does that mean in C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates

Say that we have the following:

```
template <class T, int i>
```

I understand that `T` will be whatever type being passed to some function. But, what does the `int i` portion mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It means it's parameterised by an integer value known at compile time.

Comment: For example, so you can say `std::array<int, 42> a;`

Comment: It is called a 'non type template parameter', a nice reference is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters. The meaning itself is dependent on the context.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common use cases for this kind of template class syntax is to provide some fixed size number of `T`'s to handle:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class MyClass {
    std::array<T,N> theHandledInstancesOfT;
};
```

---

```
MyClass<int,42> my42IntegersManagedByMyClass;
```

See also the [`std::array<>` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare two functions, one with a template and one without:

```
int add_two(int x, int y) {
    return (x + y);
}
// add_two(3, 4) == 7

template <int x, int y>
int add_two_2() {
    return (x + y);
}
// add_two_2<3, 4>() == 7
```

In the templatized version, the values of `x` and `y` are known already at compile time. This means that the compiler can, for instance, see that `x = 3` and `y = 4` means the result is `7`, and just replace the entire function call with `7`. In the first function, however, something like this is not possible, since the compiler doesn't know the values of `x` and `y` until the program is actually run.